# Push data to array without using if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following output. it gives my API.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2018,
        "month": 6,
        "day": 11,
        "hour": 12,
        "interval": 45,
        "method": "200"
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": 11,
        "day": 11,
        "hour": 16,
        "interval": 50,
        "method": "404"
    },
    "count": 5
},
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": 11,
        "day": 11,
        "hour": 17,
        "interval": 10,
        "method": "200"
    },
    "count": 47
}}
```

I want to Push them to arrays according to method. As an example

```
twoHundArray=[
{ "x":2018,6,11,12,45,
  "y" :1},
{"x": 2016,11,11,17,10 ,
"y" :47}]

fourhundrArry=[{ "x":2018,11,11,16,50,
  "y" :5}]
```

without using if/else statement how to push them to different arrays. In here I don't know all the names of methods.so cannot use if statement for "method".that is the problem here.

Comment: What do you mean?why you can not use `if/else` statment?what is the condition for separation?how do you want them to be divided?

Comment: What form does the original output come in? Is that in an array? That is not valid syntax

Comment: in here according to "method" i want to create array and push record to it. there are several methods.so i can't create arrays for each. it is inefficient. so i want to something that can be use to push these results to array.

Comment: hey join [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173111/for-pawani-santhara)

Comment: is this you want - 

`twoHundArray = arr.filter((item)=>item._id.method <400);
    fourhundrArry = arr.filter((item)=>item._id.method >=400));`

also in above snippet, that's not a valid array object.

Comment: @Manoj First one needs `&& item._id.method < 400`

Comment: yes. this "method" is http status codes. according to them i want to create arrays.

Comment: @Barmar, gotcha

Comment: previously i used this. 
                        if (methodTyp === "200"){

                            GETArray.push(element);

                        } else if(methodTyp === "400"){

                            POSTArray.push(element); }

Comment: @PawaniSanthara - What is the logic of naming the different arrays like `twoHundArray` or `fourHundArray`. How do you map them to 200 and 404?

Answer (score 1):

The original object is invalid. You can't have elements in an object without specifying the keys. I've assumed that it is an array.

Secondly, there is no way of pushing elements to different arrays without knowing their names. So the judgement of pushing the elements to different variables will have to be based on `if/else` conditions. Additionally, creation of those variables will vary based on the groups, as `method` could have been any value.

If you agree to group the objects based on the values `method` have, here is a way to do this:

```js
const data = [{"_id":{"year":2018,"month":6,"day":11,"hour":12,"interval":45,"method":"200"},"count":1},{"_id":{"year":2016,"month":11,"day":11,"hour":16,"interval":50,"method":"404"},"count":5},{"_id":{"year":2016,"month":11,"day":11,"hour":17,"interval":10,"method":"200"},"count":47}];
const res = {};

data.forEach(item => {
  const { method, ...obj } = item['_id'];
  res[method] = res[method] || [];

  res[method].push({
    x: Object.values(obj),
    y: item.count
  });
});

console.log(res);
```

It creates an object, whose keys are `method`. The values in the object are the arrays, which contain the items grouped by `method`.

Comment: But what about `if/else` restriction? which i am curious about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.reduce and create a map based on method. Try the following:

```js
var data = [{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2018,
        "month": 6,
        "day": 11,
        "hour": 12,
        "interval": 45,
        "method": "200"
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": 11,
        "day": 11,
        "hour": 16,
        "interval": 50,
        "method": "404"
    },
    "count": 5
},
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2016,
        "month": 11,
        "day": 11,
        "hour": 17,
        "interval": 10,
        "method": "200"
    },
    "count": 47
}];

var method = data.reduce((a,o)=>{
    if(!a[o._id.method]){
      a[o._id.method] = [];
    };
    var { method, ...ob } = o._id;
    a[o._id.method].push({
      "x": Object.values(ob).join(","),
      "y" : o.count
    });
     return a;
}, {});
console.log(method);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with `status:values` key/pair using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and post that using [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and default assignment, create independent variables.

```js
const arr = [{"_id":{"year":2018,"month":6,"day":11,"hour":12,"interval":45,"method":"200"},"count":1},{"_id":{"year":2016,"month":11,"day":11,"hour":16,"interval":50,"method":"404"},"count":5},{"_id":{"year":2016,"month":11,"day":11,"hour":17,"interval":10,"method":"200"},"count":47}];

let obj = arr.reduce((a,c) => {
  a[c._id.method] = a[c._id.method] || [];
  a[c._id.method].push({"x" : Object.values(c._id).join(),  "y" : c.count});
  return a;
},{});

/* You can add an entry here for every status type, it will pick the 
** value from object and if not present will be defaulted to an empty array */
const {200 : twoHundArray=[], 404 : fourHundArray=[], 300 : threeHundArray=[]} = obj;
console.log(twoHundArray);
console.log(fourHundArray);
console.log(threeHundArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Palani**, I'll suggest you to use an object to gather all the required information.

Please have a look at the below code and let me know any suggestions/modifications if you need.

```
var timeDataArr = [
    {
        "_id": {
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 6,
            "day": 11,
            "hour": 12,
            "interval": 45,
            "method": "200"
        },
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "year": 2016,
            "month": 11,
            "day": 11,
            "hour": 16,
            "interval": 50,
            "method": "404"
        },
        "count": 5
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "year": 2016,
            "month": 11,
            "day": 11,
            "hour": 17,
            "interval": 10,
            "method": "200"
        },
        "count": 47
    }
]

// An object that maps 'method' to its related data array
var newTimeData = {}

for(var timeData of timeDataArr) {
    var obj = timeData["_id"];
    var arr = [obj["year"], obj["month"], obj["day"], obj["hour"], obj["interval"]];

    var newObj = {
        "x": arr.join(", "),
        "y": timeData["count"],
    }

    if(newTimeData[obj["method"] + "Array"]) { // method found
        newTimeData[obj["method"] + "Array"].push(newObj)
    } else { // method not found
        newTimeData[obj["method"] + "Array"] = [newObj]
    }
}

// PRETTY PRINTING OBJECT 
console.log(JSON.stringify(newTimeData, undefined, 4))
/*...
        {
            "200Array": [
                {
                    "x": "2018, 6, 11, 12, 45",
                    "y": 1
                },
                {
                    "x": "2016, 11, 11, 17, 10",
                    "y": 47
                }
            ],
            "404Array": [
                {
                    "x": "2016, 11, 11, 16, 50",
                    "y": 5
                }
            ]
        }
...*/


// PRETTY PRINTING ARRAY POINTED BY '200Array' key
console.log(JSON.stringify(newTimeData["200Array"], undefined, 4))
/*...
        [
            {
                "x": "2018, 6, 11, 12, 45",
                "y": 1
            },
            {
                "x": "2016, 11, 11, 17, 10",
                "y": 47
            }
        ]
...*/

// PRETTY PRINTING ARRAY POINTED BY '404Array' key
console.log(JSON.stringify(newTimeData["404Array"], undefined, 4))
/*...
        [
            {
                "x": "2016, 11, 11, 16, 50",
                "y": 5
            }
        ]
...*/
```

#### Output »

```
H:\RishikeshAgrawani\Projects\Sof\FilterArrays>node FilterArrays.js
{
    "200Array": [
        {
            "x": "2018, 6, 11, 12, 45",
            "y": 1
        },
        {
            "x": "2016, 11, 11, 17, 10",
            "y": 47
        }
    ],
    "404Array": [
        {
            "x": "2016, 11, 11, 16, 50",
            "y": 5
        }
    ]
}
[
    {
        "x": "2018, 6, 11, 12, 45",
        "y": 1
    },
    {
        "x": "2016, 11, 11, 17, 10",
        "y": 47
    }
]
[
    {
        "x": "2016, 11, 11, 16, 50",
        "y": 5
    }
]
```